# Kotlin generic class to math numbers

Tags: java, class, generics, kotlin

so i just learn generic classes with Kotlin language programming , i just write code that math numbers with generic class but i don't know where is the problem exactly

My Code :

```
class Third<D, E> {    
    var num1: D? = null
    var num2: E? = null

    fun print_math_formula(b: D, c: E) {        
        val code_of_Formula: Int = 1
        val num1 = b
        val num2 = c

        var num1+num2
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>){
   var obj4 = Third<Int, Int>()
   obj4.print_math_formula(5, 6)
}
```

Comment: `var num1+num2` is not valid Kotlin syntax.

Comment: var numbersResulttt = num1 + num2

Comment: In both cases it does not work

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "doesn't work"?  What do you expect/want the code to do?  What actual problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact code you're trying to compile, and then we can explain what the problem is.

Comment: the answer in object i just want to addition numbers

Comment: i know there are easy way , but i want to try that in generic class because i am learned it recently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code above won't compile because you're trying to use the `+` operator in the generic class, but the generic class has no idea you're working with numbers. As far as the compiler is concerned, types `D` and `E` could be anything, e.g. two completely unrelated objects. So it can't just add them together.

A generic class should be used when you have a class that operates in a generic way on a given type of object. For example the standard `List` type is a generic class as it can store a list of objects of a given type. If you construct an instance of `List<String>`, that instance can store a list of strings. If you construct an instance of `List<Int>`, that instance stores a list of integers.

In your case you're doing something more specific which only works with certain types, e.g. numbers. Now, you can, when creating a generic class, say that the type of object it can operate on is limited, e.g. implements some interface. So in your case if you know this class is always going to work with numbers, you could say that you class only operates on subclasses of `Number`, e.g.

```
class Third<D: Number, E: Number>
```

`Int`, `Long`, etc., are all subclasses of `Number`. However this won't help you much in this specific case, because the `+` operator isn't on the `Number` base class: it's implemented differently on each of the subclasses. Specifying that the types `D` and `E` must be subclasses of `Number` will only allow you to call methods that exist on the `Number` class itself. For example you could do this:

```
val test = num1.toDouble() + num2.toDouble()
```

Because `toDouble` is declared as a method on the `Number` class.  However I don't think this is a great idea, really, as any sort of conversion can cause issues, e.g. rounding, etc.

Maybe in this particular case generics isn't the right solution. If you're just trying to get your head around generics, maybe find a different example, or create some custom classes that derive from a common base class, and work with that instead.

Comment: so when i should use generic classes .. , I did not understand it well

Comment: Have updated my answer. Hopefully it answers your question.